# In Ionic and Vue.js. How to fetch or “call” data from one file to another?

Tags: vue.js, ionic-framework

I’m new to both Ionic and Vue.js. I’m taking advantage of this summer break to start learning both.

I’m building a mobile app for this purpose and so far, so good. However, I have found and issue that I hope you could help me with. Namely, how to fetch or “call” data from one file to another (Is it called routing?).

In my app, I am trying to start/open a function named myFunction() from one of the pages (quiz.vue) when I call it using v-on:click="myFunction3".

This function is located in a JS file called quizz.js, and it is located in the assets folder. This is its path: `(“./assets/js/quizz.js”)`.

I have tried many things to make it work and finally it is working as it should. However, I think my solution is not optimal as it keeps throwing `“Uncaught TypeErrors”` in the console of the Developer’s Tool…even though it works.

My solution was to push the function inside methods: `this.$router.push(myFunction3())`

Also, when running the app, it says that `myFunction()` , and other functions in the same `quizz.js` file,  “is define but never used”.

If you could advise me with anything, I would be most grateful. I am still a beginner so please explain it to me in as simple a manner as possible.

```
methods:{
  openMenu(){
    menuController.open("app-menu")
},
  myFunction3(){
    this.$router.push(myFunction3())        
},
```

Below, the quizz.js file:

```js
var mlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
mlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    var myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

        
        
        
        const quiz = myObj.results[0]['question'];
        const correctAnswer = myObj.results[0]['correct_answer'];
        
        const incorrect = myObj.results[0]['incorrect_answers'];
        incorrect.push(correctAnswer);
        shuffle(incorrect);
        
        
        
        document.getElementById("ans").innerHTML = quiz;
                                

        var text = "";
        var val = 0;
        var i;      
        for (i = 0; i < incorrect.length; i++) {
            
            if(incorrect[i] == correctAnswer){
                text += "<ion-button fill='outline' id='right' onClick='increment();myFunc();'/><b>" + incorrect[i] + "</b></ion-button></br>";
                val = val + 1;
  
            }else{
                text += "<ion-button fill='outline' class='wrong' onClick='myFunc2();'/><b>" + incorrect[i] + "</b></ion-button></br>";
                
            }
            
            
        }
        document.getElementById("ans5").innerHTML = text;               
        
  }   
  
};

var j=0; 
function myFunction3() {
    document.getElementById("ans6").innerHTML = "";
    mlhttp.open("GET", "https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=1", true);
    mlhttp.send();             
    j++;       
    document.getElementById('ans11').innerHTML=j;
}

    
  

function shuffle(array) {
  for (let i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    let j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    [array[i], array[j]] = [array[j], array[i]];
  }
}     


        function myFunc(){
            document.getElementById("ans6").innerHTML = "<h1 style='color:green'><i class='fa fa-check'></i> That is correct!</h1>";
            document.getElementById("right").style.color = "white";
            document.getElementById("right").style.backgroundColor = "green";
            var audio = new Audio('./assets/sound/win.mp3');
            audio.play();


        }
        
        function myFunc2(){
            document.getElementById("ans6").innerHTML = "<h1 style='color:red'><i class='fa fa-thumbs-down' ></i>Wrong Answer! </h1>";          
            document.getElementById("right").style.color = "white";
            document.getElementById("right").style.backgroundColor = "green";
            
            var x = document.getElementsByClassName("wrong");
            var i;
            for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            x[i].style.backgroundColor = "rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.8)";
            x[i].style.color = "white";
            }           
            
            
            //document.getElementById("wrong").style.color = "red";
            var audio = new Audio('./assets/sound/wrong.mp3');
            audio.play();
            
        }


var i=0; 
function increment() {           
    i++;       
    document.getElementById('ans10').innerHTML=i;
}
```

Comment: you should follow some vue tuts, essentially you would export the function with export, or module.exports and then import it in the component, also you should port it to be usable in vue, changing the dom with document.getElementById('ans10').innerHTML etc will only lead to more issues

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I will do that. That much I already suspected, that it had to do with importing and exporting it in the components. Also, what you say about making it usable for Vue is true. The “document.getElementById('ans10').innerHTML” part was  originally done with declaratively rendering data to the DOM (<div id="app"> {{ message }}</div>) etc. but I had some issues making it work. I have done an exact copy of this project only using CDNs of both Vue.j and Ionic and it works perfectly. Maybe as a beginners I should not start with vue-cli.